# List.AddRange not working

Tags: c#-4.0

I have following code but when i add more files to payLoad.Files it doesn't give me any exception and it won't add files to the payload.

Could anyone help me

```
string xmlTestPayload = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, @"Services\STestPayload.xml")).ToString();

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(STestPayload));

STestPayload payLoad = null;
using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlTestPayload))
{
    payLoad = (STestPayload)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
if (payLoad != null)
{
    TestFile[] files = GetDocumentList(DocumentList);
    if (files != null && files.Count() > 0)
    {
    //not working
        payLoad.Files.ToList().AddRange(files);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new list but not storing returning value, try this:

```
var myList =  payLoad.Files.ToList();
myList.AddRange(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change IList into List to make use of AddRange. When you use IList, it doesn't support AddRange, hence we use .ToList() where there is temporary list created and elements from other lists are added to that unknown (we don't know its location as it is temp) and that's why we don't see the list never get added values.